# Azure Devops Boards- Different Teams with same backlog possible?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible to have a kind of **view** of the tasks in Boards/ Sprints of a common backlog but for the different people in teams?

I have already built several teams and gave them the same backlog iteration in "Team Configuration -> Iterations". Now the board/sprint is empty.

If I select the overall area in "Team Configuration -> Areas" it shows the tasks of the backlog, but not in relation to the people in the team, but for all the people. 
Is there a way to change that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Boards (and Backlogs) are for teams by Area

If you are wanting to have a different "view" of the work items in a backlog between teamA and teamB, then the answer is YES. In this case you would have the items in a common backlog and then divide that backlog into sections using areas, allowing for each team to create their own sprints under that common backlog.

### Illustrations from our setup

Our project configuration is thus:

- [Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqvcB.png)
- [Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6sSZ.png)

You'll notice that **DEV** and **MOAB** have visibility into (almost) all other areas, but other teams have visibility only into their area. This is to allow "product owner" teams to create and prioritize items in their area on their backlog and view progress on their board. Of course they can move those items into different board columns and maybe screw some stuff up, but that's when we start to shame them publicly using mass email and the blame tool (read: work items history) (jk). The boards for these teams are used for visibility only.

Our team configurations are thus:

- DSP

  - [Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWrnB.png)
  - [Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt9xP.png)
- GPC

  - [Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw61e.png)
  - [Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIpvB.png)
- DEV

  - [Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htl6C.png)
  - [Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oehY.png)
- MOAB

  - [Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc6Mn.png)
  - [Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYZsA.png)

The DEV (and MOAB >> Mother of All Backlogs) area settings are more complicated because we want the area to remain in the product owner teams view for query purposes and to allow them to see their items move across the board (if they're watching). For this reason the default DEV (and MOAB) area is root, and DEV has access to all other *team areas* and sub-areas.

*`<Edit>`*

The DEV teams select view of what is visible to MOAB is driven by the **"Backlog Iteration"**. In the illustrations you'll see that DEV has a backlog iteration path of `SYB\Backlog\Planned` where MOAB has root `SYB`.

So, for DEV, only items that are **in or under** `SYB\Backlog\Planned` iteration path are visible on its boards, where MOAB sees everything. We have added the `SYB\Backlog\Planned` iteration to the MOAB settings to allow MOAB team members (planning admins) to drag-n-drop prioritized items from the MOAB backlog (not board) into the DEV team(s) backlog.

Having 2 DEV teams you'll probably employ separate backlog iterations (ie. `SYB\Backlog\d1_Planned` and `SYB\Backlog\d2_Planned`) and add those iterations as visible to MOAB for the drag-n-drop functionality.

This setup allows planning admins and BA types to pull from the product backlog and fill the team backlog, while the team leads can plan sprints from the team backlog.

```
SYB
 +--+ Backlog -> _product owners prioritize their backlog based on the area_
    |
    +--+ d1_Planned -> _team1 leads plan sprints from here_
    |  |
    |  +---\ s1 (sprint)
    |  |
    |  +---\ s2 (sprint)
    |
    +--+ d2_Planned -> _team2 leads plan sprints from here_
       |
       +---\ s1 (stprint)
```

*`</Edit>`*

The only reason we are not using the "include sub-areas" at the root level for DEV and MOAB is because we have an area that no team sees and is for query purposes only: "Released". Moving items to this area after an iteration keeps the closed column of the board(s) trim.

Sub-areas can add further categorization/filtering to the board visibility such as by topic or project, and allow additional charting for queries by project because results queries don't need to be "hierarchical" if they query by area convention.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is gold!

So what we actually want is that we have Team1 and Team2 which are "sub-teams" of a Team. Kind of a Mother of All Teams.

Is there a way to visualize Team1 projects in both, only on the Team1 board and on the MOAT's Board? Because the MOAT's Board would be for the management to oversee projects from all teams, but we also want Team1 to visualize and work with their own projects. What I mean by projects in this case is cards.

I'm working in a sort of cross functional team with lots of people.

Comment: Absolutely you can. This seems very similar to what we have working in our org. You would basically mirror what we have, except you would have 2 DEV teams. I'll edit the answer to include the illustration of MOAB and explain the difference between that setup that allows MOAB to see everything and other teams (particularly DEV) sees only what they really care about.